# perl linux file name validation

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am trying to validate a file name in Perl and I cannot get it to work, I am not sure of what I am doing wrong. See my code below.

```
 while ($filename !~ /^[-\w]\.pl$/){
        print "Invalid file name, type another : ";
        my $filename = <STDIN>;
        chomp $filename;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working?

Answer (score 3):

> `$filename !~ /^[-\w]\.pl$/`

This expression allows only a file name that's one character long (extension not included), with that character being a word character or a dash.

I guess that you actually meant:

```
$filename !~ /^[-\w]+\.pl$/
```

Note: as commented by [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene), another issue with your regex is that it would allow a file name that has a trailing new line after the extension. To avoid that, you can use the `\z` assertion:

```
$filename !~ /^[-\w]+\.pl\z/
```

Comment: That would allow two extensions, `".pl"` and `".pl\n"`. You may want `\z` instead.

Comment: Additionally filenames starting with a dash - which are very annoying - are allowed as well. So I guess this one's better: `/^\w[-\w]*\.pl\z/`